Java exercise: removing letters from String with array of characters only removing 1 character
We're practicing recursion in class, and one of these exercises is giving me trouble (not allowed to use loops with it). I'm supposed to write a method that takes a String and an array of characters that returns the String with all of the characters in the array removed from it.
This is what I have so far. I'm struggling to get it to remove multiple characters: for example, when I input
char[] remLetArray = {'a', 's'}; 
System.out.println(removeLetters("asdfghsassaaaae", remLetArray));

it returns "sdfghssse". Here's the full thing:
    // helper method
    public static String removeLetters(String str, char[] ch, int pointer) {
        if (pointer != ch[ch.length - 1]) {
            if (str.length() == 0) {
                return removeLetters(str, ch, pointer + 1);
            } 

            if (str.charAt(0) == ch[pointer]) {
                return removeLetters(str.substring(1), ch);
            } else {
                return str.charAt(0) + removeLetters(str.substring(1), ch);
            }

        } else {
            System.out.println(str);
            if (str.length() == 0) {
                return "";
            } 

            if (str.charAt(0) == ch[pointer]) {
                return removeLetters(str.substring(1), ch);
            } else {
                return str.charAt(0) + removeLetters(str.substring(1), ch);
            }
        }
    }

    // actual method
    public static String removeLetters(String str, char[] ch) {
        return removeLetters(str, ch, 0);
    }


Recursion is when you "use the method to recall itself inside itself"!  What you are doing is called "method overloading". Overloading is when you use the same method name with different input arguments!

@SamuelMarchant the code in the question contains both recursion and method overloading.

The first problem I see is in that initial if block - you're comparing an integer to a character from the array.  I think you want to compare it to a position in the array instead - maybe something like if (pointer != ch.length - 1)

You should only put "return" as the last line of the method (e.g. once only in a method that is not of type void) !!!   Initialise a string first line in the method and assign result of ifs to the string and return the string on last line.

You're putting way too much into carrying out the task. Make use of the String#replace() method within your removeLetter() recursive method.
Start the pointer value at 0 on your first call to the removeLetter() recursive method. Within the removeLetter() method remove the character at (pointer) index 0 then, with an if statement, check to see if we're at the end of the char array. If not then within the if block increment the pointer by 1 and do another call to removeLetter() method passing the modified string (thus far) and the new pointer (index) value. The removeLetter() method should always return the modified input string. Here is an example:
public static String removeLetters(final String inputString, final char[] removeArray, final int pointer) {
    int idx = pointer;
    String newString = inputString.replace(Character.toString(removeArray[idx]), "");
    if (idx < removeArray.length - 1) {
        idx++;
        newString = removeLetters(newString, removeArray, idx);
    }
    return newString;
}

To use:
char[] remLetArray = {'a', 's'};
System.out.println(removeLetters("asdfaghsassaaaae", remLetArray, 0));

Printed result:
dfghe


Here's a one-liner. No loops, no recursion, just minimal code:
public static String removeLetters(String str, char[] ch) {
    return str.replaceAll("[" + new String(ch) + "]", "");
}

See live demo.

but note that this can fail with some special characters e.g. ^ (as first character) or - (in-between two other characters) ((kind of reminds me of Little Bobby Tables  aka SQL injection))
